# How to set Position for marker-start?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am getting mirror of arrow head. How to set in a proper position?

```js
//Constants for the SVG
var width = 500,
  height = 500;

//Set up the colour scale
var color = d3.scale.category20();

//Set up the force layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .charge(-120)
  .linkDistance(80)
  .size([width, height]);

//Append a SVG to the body of the html page. Assign this SVG as an object to svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);



//Read the data from the mis element 
var mis = document.getElementById('mis').innerHTML;
graph = JSON.parse(mis);

//Creates the graph data structure out of the json data
force.nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

//Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("marker-start", "url(#suit)") //Added 
;

//Do the same with the circles for the nodes - no 
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 8)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.group);
  })
  .call(force.drag);


//Now we are giving the SVGs co-ordinates - the force layout is generating the co-ordinates which this code is using to update the attributes of the SVG elements
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
});

//---Insert-------
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("marker")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 25)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
  .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
  .style("opacity", "0.6");
//---End Insert---
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" id="mis">
  { "nodes": [{ "name": "Myriel", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Napoleon", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1 }, { "name": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Geborand", "group": 1 }, { "name":
  "Champtercier", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Cravatte", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Count", "group": 1 }, { "name": "OldMan", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Labarre", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Valjean", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Marguerite", "group": 3 }, { "name":
  "Mme.deR", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Isabeau", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Gervais", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Tholomyes", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Listolier", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Fameuil", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Blacheville", "group": 3 }, { "name":
  "Favourite", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Dahlia", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Zephine", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Fantine", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Thenardier", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Cosette", "group": 5 }, { "name":
  "Javert", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Bamatabois", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Perpetue", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Simplice", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Woman1", "group": 2 }, {
  "name": "Judge", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Champmathieu", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Brevet", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Chenildieu", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Cochepaille", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Pontmercy", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Boulatruelle", "group":
  6 }, { "name": "Eponine", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Anzelma", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Woman2", "group": 5 }, { "name": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Gribier", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Jondrette", "group": 7 }, { "name": "Mme.Burgon", "group":
  7 }, { "name": "Gavroche", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Magnon", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5 }, { "name":
  "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Marius", "group": 8 }, { "name": "BaronessT", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mabeuf", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Enjolras", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Combeferre", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Prouvaire", "group": 8 },
  { "name": "Feuilly", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Bahorel", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Bossuet", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Joly", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Grantaire", "group": 8 }, { "name": "MotherPlutarch", "group":
  9 }, { "name": "Gueulemer", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Babet", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Claquesous", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Montparnasse", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Toussaint", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Child1", "group": 10 }, { "name": "Child2", "group":
  10 }, { "name": "Brujon", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8 }], "links": [{ "source": 1, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 2, "target": 0, "value": 8 }, { "source": 3, "target": 0, "value": 10 }, { "source": 3, "target": 2, "value":
  6 }, { "source": 4, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 5, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 6, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 7, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 8, "target": 0, "value": 2 }, { "source": 9, "target": 0, "value":
  1 }, { "source": 11, "target": 10, "value": 1 }, { "source": 11, "target": 3, "value": 3 }, { "source": 11, "target": 2, "value": 3 }, { "source": 11, "target": 0, "value": 5 }, { "source": 12, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 13, "target": 11,
  "value": 1 }, { "source": 14, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 15, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 17, "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 18, "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 18, "target": 17, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19,
  "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19, "target": 17, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19, "target": 18, "value": 4 }, { "source": 20, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 20, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 20, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, {
  "source": 20, "target": 19, "value": 4 }, { "source": 21, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 20, "value":
  5 }, { "source": 22, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 20, "value": 4 }, { "source": 22, "target":
  21, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 20, "value": 4 }, { "source":
  23, "target": 21, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 22, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 12, "value": 2 }, { "source": 23, "target": 11, "value": 9 }, { "source": 24, "target": 23, "value": 2 }, { "source": 24, "target": 11, "value": 7
  }, { "source": 25, "target": 24, "value": 13 }, { "source": 25, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 25, "target": 11, "value": 12 }, { "source": 26, "target": 24, "value": 4 }, { "source": 26, "target": 11, "value": 31 }, { "source": 26, "target":
  16, "value": 1 }, { "source": 26, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 27, "target": 11, "value": 17 }, { "source": 27, "target": 23, "value": 5 }, { "source": 27, "target": 25, "value": 5 }, { "source": 27, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  27, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 28, "target": 11, "value": 8 }, { "source": 28, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 11, "value": 2
  }, { "source": 30, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 31, "target": 30, "value": 2 }, { "source": 31, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 31, "target": 23, "value": 2 }, { "source": 31, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 32, "target":
  11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 33, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 33, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 34, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 34, "target": 29, "value": 2 }, { "source": 35, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source":
  35, "target": 34, "value": 3 }, { "source": 35, "target": 29, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 29, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 37, "target": 34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 36, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 29, "value": 1 }, { "source": 38, "target":
  34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 36, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 37, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 29, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  39, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 40, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 41, "target": 24, "value": 2 }, { "source": 41, "target": 25, "value": 3 }, { "source": 42, "target": 41, "value": 2 }, { "source": 42, "target": 25, "value": 2
  }, { "source": 42, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 43, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 43, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 43, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 44, "target": 28, "value": 3 }, { "source": 44, "target":
  11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 45, "target": 28, "value": 2 }, { "source": 47, "target": 46, "value": 1 }, { "source": 48, "target": 47, "value": 2 }, { "source": 48, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 48, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  48, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 49, "target": 26, "value": 3 }, { "source": 49, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 50, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 50, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 51, "target": 49, "value": 9
  }, { "source": 51, "target": 26, "value": 2 }, { "source": 51, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 52, "target": 51, "value": 1 }, { "source": 52, "target": 39, "value": 1 }, { "source": 53, "target": 51, "value": 1 }, { "source": 54, "target":
  51, "value": 2 }, { "source": 54, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 54, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 51, "value": 6 }, { "source": 55, "target": 49, "value": 12 }, { "source": 55, "target": 39, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  55, "target": 54, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 26, "value": 21 }, { "source": 55, "target": 11, "value": 19 }, { "source": 55, "target": 16, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 25, "value": 2 }, { "source": 55, "target": 41, "value":
  5 }, { "source": 55, "target": 48, "value": 4 }, { "source": 56, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 56, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target":
  48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 58, "target": 55, "value": 7 }, { "source": 58, "target": 48, "value": 7 }, { "source": 58, "target": 27, "value": 6 }, { "source": 58, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 58, "target": 11, "value": 4 }, { "source":
  59, "target": 58, "value": 15 }, { "source": 59, "target": 55, "value": 5 }, { "source": 59, "target": 48, "value": 6 }, { "source": 59, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 60, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 60, "target": 58, "value": 4
  }, { "source": 60, "target": 59, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 58, "value": 6 }, { "source": 61, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 61, "target":
  57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 61, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 62, "target": 55, "value": 9 }, { "source": 62, "target": 58, "value": 17 }, { "source": 62, "target": 59, "value": 13 }, { "source": 62, "target": 48, "value": 7 }, { "source":
  62, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 62, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 62, "target": 61, "value": 6 }, { "source": 62, "target": 60, "value": 3 }, { "source": 63, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 63, "target": 48, "value": 5
  }, { "source": 63, "target": 62, "value": 6 }, { "source": 63, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 63, "target": 58, "value": 4 }, { "source": 63, "target": 61, "value": 3 }, { "source": 63, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 63, "target":
  55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 64, "target": 55, "value": 5 }, { "source": 64, "target": 62, "value": 12 }, { "source": 64, "target": 48, "value": 5 }, { "source": 64, "target": 63, "value": 4 }, { "source": 64, "target": 58, "value": 10 }, { "source":
  64, "target": 61, "value": 6 }, { "source": 64, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 64, "target": 59, "value": 9 }, { "source": 64, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 64, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 65, "target": 63, "value": 5
  }, { "source": 65, "target": 64, "value": 7 }, { "source": 65, "target": 48, "value": 3 }, { "source": 65, "target": 62, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 58, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 61, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target":
  60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 65, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 65, "target": 55, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 64, "value": 3 }, { "source": 66, "target": 58, "value": 3 }, { "source":
  66, "target": 59, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 62, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 65, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 63, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 61, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 66, "target": 60, "value": 1 }, { "source": 67, "target": 57, "value": 3 }, { "source": 68, "target": 25, "value": 5 }, { "source": 68, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target":
  27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 25, "value": 6 }, { "source": 69, "target": 68, "value": 6 }, { "source": 69, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  69, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 27, "value": 2 }, { "source": 69, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 25, "value": 4 }, { "source": 70, "target": 69, "value": 4
  }, { "source": 70, "target": 68, "value": 4 }, { "source": 70, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target":
  58, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 69, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 68, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 70, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  71, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 72, "target": 26, "value": 2 }, { "source": 72, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 72, "target": 11, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 73, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 74, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 74, "target": 73, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 69, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 68, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target":
  25, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 70, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 71, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 64, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  76, "target": 65, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 66, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 63, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 62, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 58, "value": 1
  }] }
</script>
```

Output Should be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. I've rotated the path and adjusted the viewBox so it's still visible.

```js
//Constants for the SVG
var width = 500,
  height = 500;

//Set up the colour scale
var color = d3.scale.category20();

//Set up the force layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .charge(-120)
  .linkDistance(80)
  .size([width, height]);

//Append a SVG to the body of the html page. Assign this SVG as an object to svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);



//Read the data from the mis element 
var mis = document.getElementById('mis').innerHTML;
graph = JSON.parse(mis);

//Creates the graph data structure out of the json data
force.nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

//Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("marker-start", "url(#suit)") //Added 
;

//Do the same with the circles for the nodes - no 
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 8)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.group);
  })
  .call(force.drag);


//Now we are giving the SVGs co-ordinates - the force layout is generating the co-ordinates which this code is using to update the attributes of the SVG elements
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
});

//---Insert-------
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("marker")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("viewBox", "-10 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", -25)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(180)")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
  .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
  .style("opacity", "0.6");
//---End Insert---
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" id="mis">
  { "nodes": [{ "name": "Myriel", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Napoleon", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1 }, { "name": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Geborand", "group": 1 }, { "name":
  "Champtercier", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Cravatte", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Count", "group": 1 }, { "name": "OldMan", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Labarre", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Valjean", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Marguerite", "group": 3 }, { "name":
  "Mme.deR", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Isabeau", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Gervais", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Tholomyes", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Listolier", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Fameuil", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Blacheville", "group": 3 }, { "name":
  "Favourite", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Dahlia", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Zephine", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Fantine", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Thenardier", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Cosette", "group": 5 }, { "name":
  "Javert", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Bamatabois", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Perpetue", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Simplice", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Woman1", "group": 2 }, {
  "name": "Judge", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Champmathieu", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Brevet", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Chenildieu", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Cochepaille", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Pontmercy", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Boulatruelle", "group":
  6 }, { "name": "Eponine", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Anzelma", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Woman2", "group": 5 }, { "name": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Gribier", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Jondrette", "group": 7 }, { "name": "Mme.Burgon", "group":
  7 }, { "name": "Gavroche", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Magnon", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5 }, { "name":
  "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Marius", "group": 8 }, { "name": "BaronessT", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mabeuf", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Enjolras", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Combeferre", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Prouvaire", "group": 8 },
  { "name": "Feuilly", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Bahorel", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Bossuet", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Joly", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Grantaire", "group": 8 }, { "name": "MotherPlutarch", "group":
  9 }, { "name": "Gueulemer", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Babet", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Claquesous", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Montparnasse", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Toussaint", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Child1", "group": 10 }, { "name": "Child2", "group":
  10 }, { "name": "Brujon", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8 }], "links": [{ "source": 1, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 2, "target": 0, "value": 8 }, { "source": 3, "target": 0, "value": 10 }, { "source": 3, "target": 2, "value":
  6 }, { "source": 4, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 5, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 6, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 7, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 8, "target": 0, "value": 2 }, { "source": 9, "target": 0, "value":
  1 }, { "source": 11, "target": 10, "value": 1 }, { "source": 11, "target": 3, "value": 3 }, { "source": 11, "target": 2, "value": 3 }, { "source": 11, "target": 0, "value": 5 }, { "source": 12, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 13, "target": 11,
  "value": 1 }, { "source": 14, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 15, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 17, "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 18, "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 18, "target": 17, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19,
  "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19, "target": 17, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19, "target": 18, "value": 4 }, { "source": 20, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 20, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 20, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, {
  "source": 20, "target": 19, "value": 4 }, { "source": 21, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 20, "value":
  5 }, { "source": 22, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 20, "value": 4 }, { "source": 22, "target":
  21, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 20, "value": 4 }, { "source":
  23, "target": 21, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 22, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 12, "value": 2 }, { "source": 23, "target": 11, "value": 9 }, { "source": 24, "target": 23, "value": 2 }, { "source": 24, "target": 11, "value": 7
  }, { "source": 25, "target": 24, "value": 13 }, { "source": 25, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 25, "target": 11, "value": 12 }, { "source": 26, "target": 24, "value": 4 }, { "source": 26, "target": 11, "value": 31 }, { "source": 26, "target":
  16, "value": 1 }, { "source": 26, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 27, "target": 11, "value": 17 }, { "source": 27, "target": 23, "value": 5 }, { "source": 27, "target": 25, "value": 5 }, { "source": 27, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  27, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 28, "target": 11, "value": 8 }, { "source": 28, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 11, "value": 2
  }, { "source": 30, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 31, "target": 30, "value": 2 }, { "source": 31, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 31, "target": 23, "value": 2 }, { "source": 31, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 32, "target":
  11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 33, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 33, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 34, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 34, "target": 29, "value": 2 }, { "source": 35, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source":
  35, "target": 34, "value": 3 }, { "source": 35, "target": 29, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 29, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 37, "target": 34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 36, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 29, "value": 1 }, { "source": 38, "target":
  34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 36, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 37, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 29, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  39, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 40, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 41, "target": 24, "value": 2 }, { "source": 41, "target": 25, "value": 3 }, { "source": 42, "target": 41, "value": 2 }, { "source": 42, "target": 25, "value": 2
  }, { "source": 42, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 43, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 43, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 43, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 44, "target": 28, "value": 3 }, { "source": 44, "target":
  11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 45, "target": 28, "value": 2 }, { "source": 47, "target": 46, "value": 1 }, { "source": 48, "target": 47, "value": 2 }, { "source": 48, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 48, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  48, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 49, "target": 26, "value": 3 }, { "source": 49, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 50, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 50, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 51, "target": 49, "value": 9
  }, { "source": 51, "target": 26, "value": 2 }, { "source": 51, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 52, "target": 51, "value": 1 }, { "source": 52, "target": 39, "value": 1 }, { "source": 53, "target": 51, "value": 1 }, { "source": 54, "target":
  51, "value": 2 }, { "source": 54, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 54, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 51, "value": 6 }, { "source": 55, "target": 49, "value": 12 }, { "source": 55, "target": 39, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  55, "target": 54, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 26, "value": 21 }, { "source": 55, "target": 11, "value": 19 }, { "source": 55, "target": 16, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 25, "value": 2 }, { "source": 55, "target": 41, "value":
  5 }, { "source": 55, "target": 48, "value": 4 }, { "source": 56, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 56, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target":
  48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 58, "target": 55, "value": 7 }, { "source": 58, "target": 48, "value": 7 }, { "source": 58, "target": 27, "value": 6 }, { "source": 58, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 58, "target": 11, "value": 4 }, { "source":
  59, "target": 58, "value": 15 }, { "source": 59, "target": 55, "value": 5 }, { "source": 59, "target": 48, "value": 6 }, { "source": 59, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 60, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 60, "target": 58, "value": 4
  }, { "source": 60, "target": 59, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 58, "value": 6 }, { "source": 61, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 61, "target":
  57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 61, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 62, "target": 55, "value": 9 }, { "source": 62, "target": 58, "value": 17 }, { "source": 62, "target": 59, "value": 13 }, { "source": 62, "target": 48, "value": 7 }, { "source":
  62, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 62, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 62, "target": 61, "value": 6 }, { "source": 62, "target": 60, "value": 3 }, { "source": 63, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 63, "target": 48, "value": 5
  }, { "source": 63, "target": 62, "value": 6 }, { "source": 63, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 63, "target": 58, "value": 4 }, { "source": 63, "target": 61, "value": 3 }, { "source": 63, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 63, "target":
  55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 64, "target": 55, "value": 5 }, { "source": 64, "target": 62, "value": 12 }, { "source": 64, "target": 48, "value": 5 }, { "source": 64, "target": 63, "value": 4 }, { "source": 64, "target": 58, "value": 10 }, { "source":
  64, "target": 61, "value": 6 }, { "source": 64, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 64, "target": 59, "value": 9 }, { "source": 64, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 64, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 65, "target": 63, "value": 5
  }, { "source": 65, "target": 64, "value": 7 }, { "source": 65, "target": 48, "value": 3 }, { "source": 65, "target": 62, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 58, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 61, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target":
  60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 65, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 65, "target": 55, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 64, "value": 3 }, { "source": 66, "target": 58, "value": 3 }, { "source":
  66, "target": 59, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 62, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 65, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 63, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 61, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 66, "target": 60, "value": 1 }, { "source": 67, "target": 57, "value": 3 }, { "source": 68, "target": 25, "value": 5 }, { "source": 68, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target":
  27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 25, "value": 6 }, { "source": 69, "target": 68, "value": 6 }, { "source": 69, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  69, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 27, "value": 2 }, { "source": 69, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 25, "value": 4 }, { "source": 70, "target": 69, "value": 4
  }, { "source": 70, "target": 68, "value": 4 }, { "source": 70, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target":
  58, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 69, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 68, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 70, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  71, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 72, "target": 26, "value": 2 }, { "source": 72, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 72, "target": 11, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 73, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 74, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 74, "target": 73, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 69, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 68, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target":
  25, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 70, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 71, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 64, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  76, "target": 65, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 66, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 63, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 62, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 58, "value": 1
  }] }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure of having your marker positioned at the **start** of the line?

```
.style("marker-start", "url(#suit)") //Added
```

This seems to be counter-intuitive; I would expect the arrows to be pointing towards their targets. If you position the markers at the end of the line, everything looks fine.

In case you really want them to point to the opposite direction, it would be easier to also use `marker-end` and swap `source` and `target` for the links. This will only just reverse the links' orientation without having any side-effects nor doing any harm to your data.

```
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;   // d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;   // d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;   // d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;   // d.target.y;
    });
```

```js
//Constants for the SVG
var width = 500,
  height = 500;

//Set up the colour scale
var color = d3.scale.category20();

//Set up the force layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .charge(-120)
  .linkDistance(80)
  .size([width, height]);

//Append a SVG to the body of the html page. Assign this SVG as an object to svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);



//Read the data from the mis element 
var mis = document.getElementById('mis').innerHTML;
graph = JSON.parse(mis);

//Creates the graph data structure out of the json data
force.nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

//Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("marker-end", "url(#suit)") //Added 
;

//Do the same with the circles for the nodes - no 
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 8)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.group);
  })
  .call(force.drag);


//Now we are giving the SVGs co-ordinates - the force layout is generating the co-ordinates which this code is using to update the attributes of the SVG elements
force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;   // d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;   // d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;   // d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;   // d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
});

//---Insert-------
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("marker")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 25)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5 L10,0 L0, -5")
  .style("stroke", "#4679BD")
  .style("opacity", "0.6");
//---End Insert---
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" id="mis">
  { "nodes": [{ "name": "Myriel", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Napoleon", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1 }, { "name": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Geborand", "group": 1 }, { "name":
  "Champtercier", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Cravatte", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Count", "group": 1 }, { "name": "OldMan", "group": 1 }, { "name": "Labarre", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Valjean", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Marguerite", "group": 3 }, { "name":
  "Mme.deR", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Isabeau", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Gervais", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Tholomyes", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Listolier", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Fameuil", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Blacheville", "group": 3 }, { "name":
  "Favourite", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Dahlia", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Zephine", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Fantine", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Thenardier", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Cosette", "group": 5 }, { "name":
  "Javert", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Bamatabois", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Perpetue", "group": 3 }, { "name": "Simplice", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Woman1", "group": 2 }, {
  "name": "Judge", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Champmathieu", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Brevet", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Chenildieu", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Cochepaille", "group": 2 }, { "name": "Pontmercy", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Boulatruelle", "group":
  6 }, { "name": "Eponine", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Anzelma", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Woman2", "group": 5 }, { "name": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Gribier", "group": 0 }, { "name": "Jondrette", "group": 7 }, { "name": "Mme.Burgon", "group":
  7 }, { "name": "Gavroche", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Magnon", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5 }, { "name":
  "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Marius", "group": 8 }, { "name": "BaronessT", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Mabeuf", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Enjolras", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Combeferre", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Prouvaire", "group": 8 },
  { "name": "Feuilly", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Bahorel", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Bossuet", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Joly", "group": 8 }, { "name": "Grantaire", "group": 8 }, { "name": "MotherPlutarch", "group":
  9 }, { "name": "Gueulemer", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Babet", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Claquesous", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Montparnasse", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Toussaint", "group": 5 }, { "name": "Child1", "group": 10 }, { "name": "Child2", "group":
  10 }, { "name": "Brujon", "group": 4 }, { "name": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8 }], "links": [{ "source": 1, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 2, "target": 0, "value": 8 }, { "source": 3, "target": 0, "value": 10 }, { "source": 3, "target": 2, "value":
  6 }, { "source": 4, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 5, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 6, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 7, "target": 0, "value": 1 }, { "source": 8, "target": 0, "value": 2 }, { "source": 9, "target": 0, "value":
  1 }, { "source": 11, "target": 10, "value": 1 }, { "source": 11, "target": 3, "value": 3 }, { "source": 11, "target": 2, "value": 3 }, { "source": 11, "target": 0, "value": 5 }, { "source": 12, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 13, "target": 11,
  "value": 1 }, { "source": 14, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 15, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 17, "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 18, "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 18, "target": 17, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19,
  "target": 16, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19, "target": 17, "value": 4 }, { "source": 19, "target": 18, "value": 4 }, { "source": 20, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 20, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 20, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, {
  "source": 20, "target": 19, "value": 4 }, { "source": 21, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 21, "target": 20, "value":
  5 }, { "source": 22, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 22, "target": 20, "value": 4 }, { "source": 22, "target":
  21, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 16, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 17, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 18, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 19, "value": 3 }, { "source": 23, "target": 20, "value": 4 }, { "source":
  23, "target": 21, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 22, "value": 4 }, { "source": 23, "target": 12, "value": 2 }, { "source": 23, "target": 11, "value": 9 }, { "source": 24, "target": 23, "value": 2 }, { "source": 24, "target": 11, "value": 7
  }, { "source": 25, "target": 24, "value": 13 }, { "source": 25, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 25, "target": 11, "value": 12 }, { "source": 26, "target": 24, "value": 4 }, { "source": 26, "target": 11, "value": 31 }, { "source": 26, "target":
  16, "value": 1 }, { "source": 26, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 27, "target": 11, "value": 17 }, { "source": 27, "target": 23, "value": 5 }, { "source": 27, "target": 25, "value": 5 }, { "source": 27, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  27, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 28, "target": 11, "value": 8 }, { "source": 28, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 29, "target": 11, "value": 2
  }, { "source": 30, "target": 23, "value": 1 }, { "source": 31, "target": 30, "value": 2 }, { "source": 31, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 31, "target": 23, "value": 2 }, { "source": 31, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 32, "target":
  11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 33, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 33, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 34, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 34, "target": 29, "value": 2 }, { "source": 35, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source":
  35, "target": 34, "value": 3 }, { "source": 35, "target": 29, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 36, "target": 29, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 37, "target": 34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 36, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 37, "target": 29, "value": 1 }, { "source": 38, "target":
  34, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 35, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 36, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 37, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 38, "target": 29, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  39, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 40, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 41, "target": 24, "value": 2 }, { "source": 41, "target": 25, "value": 3 }, { "source": 42, "target": 41, "value": 2 }, { "source": 42, "target": 25, "value": 2
  }, { "source": 42, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 43, "target": 11, "value": 3 }, { "source": 43, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 43, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 44, "target": 28, "value": 3 }, { "source": 44, "target":
  11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 45, "target": 28, "value": 2 }, { "source": 47, "target": 46, "value": 1 }, { "source": 48, "target": 47, "value": 2 }, { "source": 48, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 48, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  48, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 49, "target": 26, "value": 3 }, { "source": 49, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 50, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 50, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 51, "target": 49, "value": 9
  }, { "source": 51, "target": 26, "value": 2 }, { "source": 51, "target": 11, "value": 2 }, { "source": 52, "target": 51, "value": 1 }, { "source": 52, "target": 39, "value": 1 }, { "source": 53, "target": 51, "value": 1 }, { "source": 54, "target":
  51, "value": 2 }, { "source": 54, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 54, "target": 26, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 51, "value": 6 }, { "source": 55, "target": 49, "value": 12 }, { "source": 55, "target": 39, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  55, "target": 54, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 26, "value": 21 }, { "source": 55, "target": 11, "value": 19 }, { "source": 55, "target": 16, "value": 1 }, { "source": 55, "target": 25, "value": 2 }, { "source": 55, "target": 41, "value":
  5 }, { "source": 55, "target": 48, "value": 4 }, { "source": 56, "target": 49, "value": 1 }, { "source": 56, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 57, "target":
  48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 58, "target": 55, "value": 7 }, { "source": 58, "target": 48, "value": 7 }, { "source": 58, "target": 27, "value": 6 }, { "source": 58, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 58, "target": 11, "value": 4 }, { "source":
  59, "target": 58, "value": 15 }, { "source": 59, "target": 55, "value": 5 }, { "source": 59, "target": 48, "value": 6 }, { "source": 59, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 60, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 60, "target": 58, "value": 4
  }, { "source": 60, "target": 59, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 58, "value": 6 }, { "source": 61, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 61, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 61, "target":
  57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 61, "target": 55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 62, "target": 55, "value": 9 }, { "source": 62, "target": 58, "value": 17 }, { "source": 62, "target": 59, "value": 13 }, { "source": 62, "target": 48, "value": 7 }, { "source":
  62, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 62, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 62, "target": 61, "value": 6 }, { "source": 62, "target": 60, "value": 3 }, { "source": 63, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 63, "target": 48, "value": 5
  }, { "source": 63, "target": 62, "value": 6 }, { "source": 63, "target": 57, "value": 2 }, { "source": 63, "target": 58, "value": 4 }, { "source": 63, "target": 61, "value": 3 }, { "source": 63, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 63, "target":
  55, "value": 1 }, { "source": 64, "target": 55, "value": 5 }, { "source": 64, "target": 62, "value": 12 }, { "source": 64, "target": 48, "value": 5 }, { "source": 64, "target": 63, "value": 4 }, { "source": 64, "target": 58, "value": 10 }, { "source":
  64, "target": 61, "value": 6 }, { "source": 64, "target": 60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 64, "target": 59, "value": 9 }, { "source": 64, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 64, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 65, "target": 63, "value": 5
  }, { "source": 65, "target": 64, "value": 7 }, { "source": 65, "target": 48, "value": 3 }, { "source": 65, "target": 62, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 58, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 61, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target":
  60, "value": 2 }, { "source": 65, "target": 59, "value": 5 }, { "source": 65, "target": 57, "value": 1 }, { "source": 65, "target": 55, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 64, "value": 3 }, { "source": 66, "target": 58, "value": 3 }, { "source":
  66, "target": 59, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 62, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 65, "value": 2 }, { "source": 66, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 63, "value": 1 }, { "source": 66, "target": 61, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 66, "target": 60, "value": 1 }, { "source": 67, "target": 57, "value": 3 }, { "source": 68, "target": 25, "value": 5 }, { "source": 68, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target":
  27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 68, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 25, "value": 6 }, { "source": 69, "target": 68, "value": 6 }, { "source": 69, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  69, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 27, "value": 2 }, { "source": 69, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 69, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 25, "value": 4 }, { "source": 70, "target": 69, "value": 4
  }, { "source": 70, "target": 68, "value": 4 }, { "source": 70, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 24, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 70, "target":
  58, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 69, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 68, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 70, "value": 2 }, { "source": 71, "target": 11, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  71, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 71, "target": 25, "value": 1 }, { "source": 72, "target": 26, "value": 2 }, { "source": 72, "target": 27, "value": 1 }, { "source": 72, "target": 11, "value": 1
  }, { "source": 73, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 74, "target": 48, "value": 2 }, { "source": 74, "target": 73, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 69, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 68, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target":
  25, "value": 3 }, { "source": 75, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 41, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 70, "value": 1 }, { "source": 75, "target": 71, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 64, "value": 1 }, { "source":
  76, "target": 65, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 66, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 63, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 62, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 48, "value": 1 }, { "source": 76, "target": 58, "value": 1
  }] }
</script>
```